# Format a Number using JQuery globalization to include as few decimals as possible but as many as are required without rounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-globalization

Using the JQuery globalization plugin, I want to format numbers to use as many decimals needed to represent the correct value. Also i want the format to use as few decimals as possible.

For example the following example yields '56.12'

```
Globalize.culture('en');
console.log( Globalize.format(56,123456, 'N') );
```

i want it to yield 56.123456

Am i missing some kind of format option or other alternative?

Examples of what i want:

- 1.12 -> '1.12'
- 1.123 -> '1.123'
- 1 -> '1'

Link to library:
https://github.com/jquery/globalize/